# How to loop through multiple excel spreadsheet in order to sort every spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I think my problem is quite simple but I can't figure out how to deal with it. I will try to be as accurate as I can and show you what I tried already and what's not working.

I want to sort multiple spreadsheets.

I'm analyzing stock market prices.  Every spreadsheet has the same architecture which looks like this (simplified):

```
Date          OpenPrice             ClosePrice               Volume
30.07.2017    12                    13                       500
28.07.2017    13                    14                       650
25.07.2017    14                    11                       1200
```

etc...

I need to sort every spreadsheet backward, from the past to the future. It would  be like this :

```
Date          OpenPrice             ClosePrice               Volume
25.07.2017    14                    11                       1200
28.07.2017    13                    14                       650
30.07.2017    12                    13                       500
```

I can easily sort one spreadsheet, using either the excel sorting tool (I am sorting dates so it can be sorted alphabetically) or using a VBA script like `splitcolumn` or `splitrow` with a loop.

My problem is that I can't sort all the spreadsheets (500+) at once. The VBA scripts or the excel tool only sort one spreadsheet and I have to repeat manually the operation.

Comment: Look up a `For each worksheet in thisworkbook.sheets` loop to append to your VBA code you already have?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Current as Worksheet
For each Current in Worksheets

    ...Do the sort here. If you need to refer to sheet you are sorting, use Current

Next
```